# Check if a combo has a selected value in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Which is the best way to check if a combo has a selected value in Delphi?

Comment: `ComboBox.ItemIndex <> -1`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TComboBox.ItemIndex) (emphasis mine):

> Read ItemIndex to determine which item is selected. The first item in the list has index 0, the second item has index 1, and so on. **If no item is selected, the value of ItemIndex is -1.** If the list control supports multiple selected items, ItemIndex is the index of the selected item that has focus.

Here is an example:

```
var
  myCombo : TComboBox;
...
if (myCombo.ItemIndex <> -1) then
  // add code here
```

Comment: Spurious C-style parentheses in `if`! A blasphemy! :-)

Comment: @FreeConsulting, I try to code for best readibility (and to be consistent if another condition would be added). Did that long before coding in C, where readability only works if you code it as you would in pascal (whenever possible).

Comment: IMO, parens there only hurts readability (as long as there is no compound booleand expr)...

Comment: @FreeConsulting, it still falls into the consistency clause. I know some always use begin/end after then/else just to be consistent and to avoid simple tab errors. Anyway, readability is somewhat personal :-)